# NoSuchElementException: No value present - как правильно создать Mock объект?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Всем привет.
Есть REST приложение со Spring Boot. Пытаюсь разобраться и написать тесты для слоя Service. В качестве примера использую: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Вот мой класс тестов:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private static UserRepository userRepository;

    @MockBean
    private static CipherService cipherService;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class UserServiceImplTestContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public UserService userService() {
            return new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, cipherService);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        User user = new User("user", "password");
        userRepository.findById(user.getName());
        Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(user.getName()).get())
                .thenReturn(user);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenValidName_thenUserShouldBeFound() {
        String name = "user";
        User found = userService.findByName(name);

        AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat(found.getName()).isEqualTo(name);
    }
}
```

После запуска получаю :

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
>
> at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)    at
>   com.signing_bot.repository.UserServiceTest.setUp(UserServiceTest.java:45)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, где я косячу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу несколько ошибок.

```
 Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(user.getName()).get())
            .thenReturn(user)
```

Два вызова метода внутри `when` (`findById` и `get`).

```
userRepository.findById(user.getName());
```

перед `Mockito.when` не нужно.

И еще у вас два определения для `UserRepository`

```
@MockBean
private static UserRepository userRepository
```

и

```
   @Bean
   public UserService userService() {
       return new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, cipherService);
   }
```

Второе не нужно.

Comment: первое не ошибка, (метод в UserServiceImpl действительно возвращает: return userRepository.findById(name).get(); По второй ошибке, убрал второе и получил: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Comment: Если вы хотите замокать оба вызова нужно два `Mockito.when` в одном два вызова не сработают.

Comment: а вот по поводу замокать вы были правы. :) исправил правда немного по другому :) Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(user.getName()))
                .thenReturn(java.util.Optional.ofNullable(user));  Спасибо :)